# Weak and Weak* convergences implying reflexivity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Suppose that for any sequence of functionals $(\phi_n) \subseteq X^*$ we have that $\phi_n$ converges weakly to some $\phi \in X^*$ if and only if $\phi_n$ converges weakly* to $\phi.$

We know that the weak and weak* topologies on $X^*$ coincide if and only if $X$ is reflexive. Since two topological spaces that have the same convergent sequences do not need to be equal, our $X$ above does not need the weak and weak* topologies to coincide.

So what can we say about such an $X$ above? Is it still reflexive?

Comment: The topology of a metrizable space *is* determined by the convergence of its sequences.

Comment: @Berci AFAIK neither weak nor weak* topology are metrizable.

Comment: Here is one special case I guess: Suppose $X$ admits a pre-dual $Y$ that is also separable, then your property holds iff $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: Maybe use `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein–Šmulian_theorem` ?

Comment: My guess for a counterexample would be $X = C(K)$ where $K$ is compact but not sequentially compact.  Examples $K = \beta \mathbb N$ and $K = [0,1]^E$ with $|E| = \mathfrak c$.

Comment: If even the bounty does not help to answer the question, it might be worthwhile to try on MathOverflow. Bill Johnson probably knows the answer.

Comment: @Jochen: Done, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425811.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an argument for the following case:

> Suppose $X$ is separable and it admits a predual $X_\#$. Then $X$ is reflexive iff every weak* convergent sequence in $X^*$ is weak convergent.

Begin with the image of the unit ball $X_\#$ in $X^*$, this image is weak closed (since its norm closed + convex) but weak* dense in the unit ball of $X^*$ (by the Goldstine theorem). Weak closed clearly implies weak sequentially closed.

Since $X$ is separable the weak* topology on the unit ball of $X^*$ is metrisable, so every element in the unit ball can be weak* approximated by a sequence in $X_\#$. So unless $X_\#=X^*$ (ie unless $X$ is reflexive) there are  sequences that are weak* convergent but not weakly convergent.

Comment: The weak$^*$ topology on the dual of a infinite dimensional Banach space is **never** metrizable: It is sequentially complete because of Banach-Steinhaus and if it were metrizable it would be completely metrizable. But then Baire's theorem (or the open mapping theorem) would imply that this weak$^*$ topology coincides with the dual norm topology which is not true.

Comment: It is of course true that the dual unit ball with the weak$^*$ topology is metrizable.

Comment: @Jochen thank you for the correction. I think the argument itself does not change if one shifts the focus to the unit ball, and edited the answer. Is there something else I overlooked?

Comment: If $X$ is separable and in $X^*$ weak and weak$^*$ convergence of sequences are equivalent then $X$ is reflexive because so is $X^*$. As commented by @GEdgar this follows from Eberlein-Smulian (weak compactness = weak sequential compactness) and the metrizability of the dual unit ball in the weak $^*$ topology (which is thus sequentially compact).

Comment: I think that your arguments are also fine (and more elementary than Eberlein-Smulian).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an expansion of the comment by GEdgar:

Let $X$ be separable and suppose that weak and weak-* convergence of sequences coincides on $X^*$. Let $B \subset X^*$ be the (closed) unit ball.

Since $X$ is separable, the [Sequential Banach–Alaoglu theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Sequential_Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem) implies that $B$ is sequentially weak-* compact. Since weak and weak-* convergent sequences coincide in $X^*$, it follows that $B$ is sequentially weakly compact. Now, the [Eberlein–Šmulian theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eberlein%E2%80%93%C5%A0mulian_theorem) implies that $B$ is weakly compact. Finally, [Kakutani's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space#Properties) yields that $X^*$ (and, consequently, $X$) is reflexive.

Moreover, it is possible to substitute the application of the Eberlein–Šmulian theorem and Kakutani's theorem by [James' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27s_theorem): Let $f \in X^{**}$ be a linear and continuous functional on $X^*$. Since $B$ is sequentially weakly compact, it is easy to see that the supremum of $f$ is attained on $B$. Thus, James' theorem implies the reflexivity of $X^*$ (and, consequently of $X$).

Comment: Eberlein-Smulian is already rather deep but James' theorem is much harder.

Comment: I repeat the suggestion to post this question on MathOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

This, too, is a partial answer.  I originally wrote it to argue that GEdgar's suggestion of $C(\beta\mathbb{N})$ and similar are not counterexamples (i.e., your hypothetical equivalence holds for them), but flubbed a key point.  Nevertheless, my argument shows (in rather elementary fashion) that a counterexample should have to be rather exotic.

Specifically, let $K$ be any infinite compact Hausdorff space — say, $\beta\mathbb{N}$, $[0,1]^{\mathbb{R}}$, or just $\omega_1+1$ with the [ordinal topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_topology).  I will show that if $K$ admits a nontrivial convergent sequence in the sense of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.03838.pdf) — that is, a convergent sequence that is not eventually constant — then $K$ cannot be a counterexample.  Not all infinite compact Hausdorff spaces admit such a sequence because they need not be sequentially compact; in particular, such is the case for $\beta\mathbb{N}$.

Anyways, on to the proof!

Pick a maximal set $S$ of mutually singular measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra associated with the topology on $K$; $S$ always exists by Zorn's Lemma.  Endow $S$ with the discrete topology and place the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $S\times K$; the latter has a natural measure, given by $$\lambda(A)=\sum_{s\in S}{s(\{x:(s,x)\in A\})}$$

Now, $C(K)^*$  is the space of Borel-regular measures on $K$.  By Lebesgue decomposition and Radon-Nikodym, $T:C(K)^*\to L^1(S\times K)$; $$T(\mu)(s,x)=\frac{d\mu}{ds}(x)$$ (where the Radon-Nikodym derivative vanishes if $\mu\perp s$) is an isometric isomorphism.  Correspondingly $C(K)^{**}\cong L^{\infty}(S\times K)$, and I now unabashedly identify across both isomorphisms.

In particular, pick any sequence $\{\mu_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\in L^1(S\times K)^{\omega_0}$.  $\{\mu_n\}_n\overset{*}{\rightharpoonup}0$ iff, for all $f\in C(K)$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\iint_{S\times K}{f(x)\mu_n(s,x)\,d^2(s,x)}}=0$$ and $\{\mu_n\}_n\rightharpoonup0$ iff, for all $f\in L^{\infty}(S\times K)$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{\iint_{S\times K}{f(s,x)\mu_n(s,x)\,d^2(s,x)}}=0$$

With those preliminaries in hand, an easy construction now shows that the topologies of weak and weak-$*$ convergence do not coincide on sequences in $C(K)^*$.  Choose any sequence $\{q_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}\in K^{\omega_0}$ of distinct elements, tending to a limit $q_{\infty}$.  W/oLoG, for each $n$, the Dirac mass $\delta_{q_n}\in S$.  So let $$\mu_n(s,x)=\begin{cases}
1 & s=\delta_{q_{2n}} \\
-1 & s=\delta_{q_{2n+1}} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$  Then, since any $f\in C(K)$ is continuous at $q_{\infty}$, we can compute $$\iint_{S\times K}{f(x)\mu_n(s,x)\,d^2(s,x)}=f(q_{2n})-f(q_{2n+1})\to0$$ as $n\to\infty$.  But just as clearly the pointwise sum $\sum_n{\mu_n}\in L^{\infty}(S\times K)$, so that $$\iint_{S\times K}{\left(\sum_n{\mu_n}\right)(s,x)\mu_n(s,x)\,d^2(s,x)}=2\not\to0$$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The comment by M.Gonzales at MO https://mathoverflow.net/q/425811/454 claims that $\ell^\infty$ is a Grothendieck space, i.e. is a counterexample.  It seems that is a result of Grothendieck himself, 1953.  But, of course,$\ell^\infty = C(\beta\mathbb N)$.

Comment: @GEdgar: Looking through the paper Gonzales linked, some compact Hausdorff spaces don't have enough convergent sequences to apply my construction at the end; at a key point, I replaced "compact" with "sequentially compact" by accident.  I've added the missing the hypothesis to my answer.

Comment: @GEdgar: (Also, I hope this answer didn't come across as a personal attack.  I wrote this answer because your examples kept on seeming like really good candidates for a counterexample.)

Comment: A $CK)$ space is Grothendieck if and only if it contains no complemented copies of $c_0$.

Comment: @M.González: Yes, this answer gives one direction of that equality.  I think the other direction is given in your link on MO.